# Delete username from a Git repository

Tags: git, git-config

I am getting this warning when I try to set my user name in [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/):

> warning: user.name has multiple values

I have checked in a terminal window and found that I have three usernames:

```
macmini:HiBye shannoga$ git config --get-all user.name
Shani
shani
shani
```

How can I delete two of the user names?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `git config -e` and you should see something like:

```
[user]
    name = Shani
    name = shani
    name = shani
```

Delete the lines you don't want.

Comment: Hi I am new to git, what do you mean "delete the redundant lines"? can you be more deatailed

Comment: When I set these values from cmd-line it wasn't working - had multiple values, some blank. . must be a bug/config issue in my git version. . . editing the file worked.

Comment: @AlonL please don't radically change a post, instead write your own answer. See [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203183/152859) for reference.

Comment: This (very old post) doesn't work for me now, but I get the same output noted above with
`git config --global --edit`

Comment: This changes the local configuration for a specific git project, right? How can you do this for your whole system? `git config --global --edit` only gives me nothingness.

Answer (score 25):

This worked for me on my Mac:

```
git config --global --unset-all user.name
```

Answer (score 8):

The older answers above didn't work for me either anymore: in addition to editing the .gitconfig file directly, you can just run

```
git config --global --edit
```

and make your changes there.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace the wrong ones with the proper one:

```
git config --global --replace-all user.name "FName LName"
```

same applies for user mail:

```
git config --global --replace-all user.mail "mail-id@domain.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue, i thought it had something to do with the ssh key, after removing both, nothing happened but this one worked for me:

```
git config --global --edit
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: with [git1.8.1rc1](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1407184) (December 2012), the logic is different;

> "`git config --get`" used to diagnose presence of multiple definitions of the same variable in the same configuration file as an error, but **it now applies the "last one wins" rule used by the internal configuration logic**.
>
> Strictly speaking, this may be an API regression but it is expected that nobody will notice it in practice.

Answer (score 0):

If updating email address and password in your config file didn't help then probably you might be using this account with your machine for the first time. Generating and assosiating the pass phrase key with your account helps.

**References** :

- [generating a new ssh key and adding it to the ssh agent](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)
- [github_tutorial](https://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/init.html)

Answer (score 0):

The above answers didn't work for me.
Edit the `.gitconfig` file in your home directory. This is your global configuration.

Go to the home directory:

```sh
cd ~
```

edit `.gitconfig`

```yaml
[user]
    name = Your Name
    email = your.email@foo.com
```