# How to delete multiple Git user.names

Tags: git

Today is my first day trying to learn Ruby on Rails and Git using a Mac and I created multiple Git user.names by accident.

How can I delete the duplicates?

Note that I read through the different answers in the posts below and either I did not understand the answer (as I am too new to this) or those answers just did not work for me

[More than one value for the key user.name Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310974/more-than-one-value-for-the-key-user-name-git)

[Delete username from a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243407/delete-username-from-a-git-repository)

Screenshot of error on Terminal: http://bit.ly/1rLjMPC

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If it is not related to ruby or ruby-on-rails directly I would suggest to remove those tags

Comment: the config is a text file, you can always just edit it.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error messages here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from one of the links you posted. Execute the following command in your terminal with the correct username you want to use

```
git config --global --replace-all user.name "username"
```

Comment: Thank you Vimsha - it worked! I guess I did not realize I was supposed to enter the new username in there.