# Commits on github are linked to right user while pushes are linked to wrong user

Tags: github, git-commit, git-config, git

`Commits`(for new or old branch) done after changing the username and email are linked to me while `Pushes`(for both old and new branch) are for old user.

Moreover if I setup a new project or anything new as generating ssh keys I get the message in terminal as previous user. How do I remove that previous user from my system so that everything done related to `github` from my system should be related to my account.

I changed the `config file` through this link , it is also showing the correct username and email
through `git config --global user.name` or `git config --global user.email`.

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the console as

`git config --list`

It will list all your git configuration status.

then try

`git config --global --unset-all user.name`

and then

`git config --global --add user.name <your_username>`

You can try from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243407/delete-username-from-a-git-repository) also. See the *1st Answer*
Hope it might work !!!