# Problem with git config --global user.name

Tags: git

When I try to configure my username with `git config --global user.name "Michaël Doyon"`, it returns:

> warning: user.name has multiple values error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
>
> Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change user.name.

Also, when I do `git config --get user.name`, it returns `Michaël` and not `Michaël Doyon`.

Be aware that I am trying to set up git on a new computer with the same username and email that I used to set up git on my old computer (MacBook Air 2017).

Can you help me configure my username to `Michaël Doyon`?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-config%5D+multiple+values

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33638880/7976758 and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50367306/7976758

Answer (score 4):

Use `git config --global --unset-all user.name`, then
`git config --global user.name "Michaël Doyon"`. The first command will remove the offending multiple entries so that the second one will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can just bring up `~/.gitconfig` in a text editor.  It's a plain text file.