# How to fix multiple values error in git while configuring the name?

Tags: linux, git, configuration, repository, addition

```
$ git config --global user.name "Amritjyot Singh"
warning: user.name has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change user.name.
```

How to use regexp to fix this problem?

I tried git config --global user.name "Amritjyot Singh"
Expected to configure my name in git bash but this error was shown

Comment: What specific questions does the [Description](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_description)  of the `git config` command leave?

Comment: every git command has a help page you can access with `git help <command>`, the page linked by jthill is `git help config`. These pages are also accessible from the official git site, starting from https://git-scm.com/docs/ and searching for target command, or by directly accessing `https://git-scm.com/docs/git-<command>` (again: jthill's link point to that official page). The only thing with the website is : compare your local git version (`git version`) with the version of the doc you are looking at (the website shows the latest version by default)

Comment: Learn to use search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33638880/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+warning%3A+user.name+has+multiple+values

Answer (score 2):

To see where different values for a config parameter are defined :

```
$ git config --show-origin --get-all user.name
# sample output:
file:/home/wwhite/.gitconfig   Walter White
file:.git/config  Heisenberg
```

If you see several values coming from one single file:

```
file:/home/jack/.gitconfig   Jack
file:/home/jack/.gitconfig   Tyler Durden
```

you can either

- edit the mentioned configuration file with a regular text editor, and delete the erroneous value,
- or use :

```
git config [correct scope] --replace-all user.name "My Name"
```

where `[correct scope]` will probably be `--global` (if source is in `$HOME/.gitconfig`) or `--local` (<- same as empty string, if source is `.git/config`).

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you have multiple `user.name` configuration keys. Remove them all with:

```
git config --global --unset-all user.name
```

Then set it again:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `git config --global -e` to edit the global config file. According to the warning and error messages, there are multiple values like this

```
[user]
    name = foo
```

Find all of them, keep one and remove the others.